# ASP.NET Core: 404 not found when deleting record with angular 4 POST request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a full-stack application and now would like the functionality of being able to delete individual objects (questions in my db) with a button click. My API in the backend works for this purpose when I test via postman: it returns 200 OK and when I check the record is effectively deleted. However this does not work when attempting the same action through my frontend.

Back-end API:

```
    [Route("api/removeQuestion")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoveQuestion(int questionId)
    {
        Question question = _context.Questions.SingleOrDefault(q => q.QuestionId == questionId);

        if (question == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Questions.Remove(question);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Frontend API:

```
removeQuestion(questionId:number) {
var url = "http://localhost:57222/api/removeQuestion";
console.log("id is: " + questionId);
return this.http.post(url, questionId).map(
  res => <Question>res.json()[0],
  err => console.log(err)      
);
```

}

Where I call the API:

```
removeQuestion(id:number){
this.api.removeQuestion(id).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.question = res;
  },
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
);
```

}

You'll notice I'm mapping a response while I don't really need one, I did this as a workaround because my posts were not getting through at all unless I did it like this.

To the extent I understand the problem myself, it is not successfully finding the appropriate object based on the id value with SingleOrDefault and thus reverting to the default value null(?). However the id is logged correctly in my console right before the API is called, and it works when I send a manual post with postman.

Comment: you might want to change the `POST` to `DELETE` btw

Comment: I thought so too but when I did research on microsoft's help pages they do deletions with POST too. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
return this.http.post(url, {questionId:questionId}).map(
  res => <Question>res.json()[0],
  err => console.log(err)      
);
```

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: No luck with this method either unfortunately. Still 404ing me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [FromBody]:

```
public IActionResult RemoveQuestion([FromBody]int questionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had help from a friend, and he found the cause.

The API method in my backend kept attempting to deserialize what it receives, which obviously isn't possible with an integer.

I've changed functionality to pass the entire Question object, and now it works.

new code:

```
    [Route("api/removeQuestion")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoveQuestion([FromBody] Question question)
    {

        if (question == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Questions.Remove(question);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

and adjusted front end so the object is passed.

```
removeQuestion(question:Question) {
var url = "http://localhost:57222/api/removeQuestion";
return this.http.post(url,question).map(
  res => <Question>res.json()[0],
  err => console.log(err)      
);
```

}